# Azure SQL Database saving dates

Tags: sql, date, azure-sql-database

This is probably a very simple question/answer but I cannot find the appropriate info or otherwise misinterpret it. I want to save a date in simple 'YYYY-MM-DD' format in Azure SQL DB.

I'm using the following commands:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ExampleDates (ExampleDate DATE);
INSERT INTO ExampleDates (ExampleDate) VALUES ('2024-02-28');
SELECT * FROM ExampleDates;
```

And the following results:

| ExampleDate |
| --- |
| 2024-02-28T00:00:00.0000000 |

I'd expect using a DATE type column would save the data as 2024-02-28 instead of 2024-02-28T00:00:00.0000000. How is this the expected result format and how could I save it as just 2024-02-28?

Comment: Date and time values don't have a format, the value isn't being saved with one, it's just a binary value. Your ***presentation layer*** is what decides how that is displayed. If you want it *displayed* in a different way, then control that in your application code.

Answer (score 0):

To get the output in required format `yyyy-MM-dd` you can use below query:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ExampleDate) AS ExampleDate FROM ExampleDates;
```

The query uses `CONVERT()` function, it converts a value (of any type) into a specified datatype.

**Output:**

[image]

Yes, as Thom said, `date` and `time` don't have a format, and they are binary values. The presentation layer decides how the output is to be displayed. So, it's better to use application code to convert `date` into the required format. The code below is a `.NET` application code that displays the date in the required format, as shown in the output below:

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string connectionString = "******";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT ExampleDate FROM ExampleDates;";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DateTime exampleDate = reader.GetDateTime(0);
                string formattedDate = exampleDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Console.WriteLine("Formatted Date: " + formattedDate);
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```js
Formatted Date: 2024-02-28
```